# How to implement counter in the .text area without using registers?

Tags: windows, assembly

i have this assembly code in the .text segment, is it possible that i can't inc a dword that seats in the .text area. if i put some dword that seats in the .data section it works fine, i mean when i switch the line:

`01004A72   > 813D 664A0001 >CMP DWORD PTR DS:[1004A66],3E7`

with the line

```
 01004A72   > 813D 664A0001 >CMP DWORD PTR DS:[.data:0100579C],3E7



01004A66     0000           ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
01004A68     0000           ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
01004A6A     00             DB 00
01004A6B     00             DB 00
01004A6C     00             DB 00
01004A6D     00             DB 00
01004A6E     00             DB 00
01004A6F     00             DB 00
01004A70     00             DB 00
01004A71     00             DB 00
01004A72   > 813D 664A0001 >CMP DWORD PTR DS:[1004A66],3E7
01004A7C   . 74 06          JE SHORT winmine3.01004A84
01004A7E     FF05 9C570001  INC DWORD PTR DS:[1004A66]
01004A84    ^E9 CDD5FFFF    JMP winmine3.01002056
01004A89     0000           ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
01004A8B     0000           ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
01004A8D     0000           ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
01004A8F     00             DB 00
01004A90     00             DB 00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.text` segment is a read only section. You should use `.bss` `.data` or the `stack` for modifiable variables.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment

Comment: There is no ".text segment" in win32. There is code segment which is selected by `CS` register, and there can be `.text` section which can be non-writeable, if it will be compiled (linked) non-writeable.

Comment: Most compilers call the entry point section `.text`, to the extent where it is now considered to be an alternative term.

Answer (score 2):

The `.text` area is usually read only, so you can't write results to it. You could use `.data` instead, or even the stack if you really want.

Comment: ...or even heap, or even any other writeable memory page, but this is assembly-level question and it's about how to keep data in `.text` section.

Comment: Sure, but you *shouldn't* have `.text` writeable, as I mentioned on your answer. The security concerns are innumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VirtualProtect` function to make `.text` *section* writeable.

---

**Upd:** regarding security risks:
As @RaymondChen wrote, having read-write-execute page is insecure.

Attacker can exploit buffer overflow such way that it will overwrite pointer to another buffer, and attacker's code will be copied to read-write-execute (RWX) page.

But when you protect your program with a software protection tool, or just pack it with UPX, code section becomes writeable. And certain popular commercial protectors don't make it non-writeable back. It becomes funny if your dictionary has a DLL which loads into every process, and it have RWX sections.

I don't want to say that if there is a lot of "protected" programs which don't care about RWX memory, so you shouldn't care too. I want just to note that protection mechanisms like DEP are kinda overestimated.

Regarding OP question.
I don't think that it's good idea to write real applications in assembly, especially in windows, in user-mode. But it's fine to to write in assembly for educational purposes. And there is nothing wrong with writing 100-lines-long assembly program with writeable code section.

Comment: But you **really** shouldn't. Having a writeable `.text` section would entirely negate ASLR and DEP's ability to prevent exploits from being successful.

Comment: @Polynomial, `ASLR`? Please write what is ASLR and how it's related to memory pages protection flags. The same is with `DEP` - "data execution prevention" - it's not the same as "code modification prevention", right?

Comment: DEP makes it harder for an attacker because it means that by default there are no read-write-execute pages in the system. If you write-enable your code segment, then *you created a read-write-execute page in the system*: You did exactly the thing DEP was trying to prevent! You created code (executable memory) that is also data (writeable memory). Most people worry about preventing data from becoming code, but what you did was make code become data. (Note also that making code writeable also prevents code sharing between processes since each process now has a different copy of the code.)

Comment: Raymond is absolutely right. Any heap overflow, stack buffer overflow, SEH pointer exploit or other arbitrary vulnerability would allow an attacker to write a payload and execute it anywhere in the process memory, even in .text

Comment: @RaymondChen, FYI - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448065/risks-of-rwx-memory-pages